# Как сохранять объекты в коллекции по ключу

Tags: java

Что я сделал: считал из программы информацию, проверил на валидность, создал 3 класса Employee, Departament, Task (это главный)

Проблема: для каждого объекта Employee новый объект Department. У меня каждый сотрудник работает в своем уникальном подразделении, а нужно, чтобы все сотрудники из второго подразделения, относились ко второму, а из первого, к первому.

```
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException{
        Map<String, Department> DepEmployee = new HashMap<>();

        String path = args.length > 0 ? args[0] : null;

        assert path != null;
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path), "CP1251")); br) {
            while (true) {
                String line = br.readLine();
                if (line == null)
                    break;
                if (Check(line) != null) {
                    String[] strings = line.split("/");
                    Employee emp = new Employee(strings[0], new BigDecimal(strings[1]));
                    Department dep = new Department(strings[2]);
                    dep.addEmployee(emp);
                    System.out.println(strings[0] + " " + strings[1] + " " + strings[2] + " - корректна, обрабатываем");
                }
            }
            for (Map.Entry<String, Department> entry : DepEmployee.entrySet())
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Если у вас появилась другая проблема, оформите новый вопрос, нажав на кнопку "задать вопрос" слева вверху, а не стирайте старый, на который уже получен ответ. Теперь ответ совершенно не соответствует вопросу.

Comment: @pavlofff Да, знаю, в связи с этим и пришлось вызвать модератора на ответ. Причиной того, что стёр вопрос - является то, что не могу задать новый. Потому что все остальные вопросы, которые имеют отрицательный рейтинг - получили ответ более точно по проблеме и стирать там для меня не имеет смысла, а изменить, чтобы люди оценили положительно - не получится, потому что они заданы достаточно конкретно по моей ситуации.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала я бы порекомендовал сделать где-то класс, который будет хранить все созданные тобой объекты (сотрудники, департаменты) в списках. Это будет что-то типа импровизации базы данных (mock-ет), затем убедиться, что все твои классы которые просто являются объектами хранения данных имплементируют интерфейс *java.io.Serializable* (или для сложных объектов интерфейс *java.io.Externalizable*, но этот вариант чуть посложней, так как требует реализовать некоторые методы этого интерфейса. В отличии от *java.io.Serializable*, который не содержит ни каких методов)

У тебя должно получиться что-то вроде:

```
public class Employee implements Serializable{
   ...
}

public class Department implements Serializable{
   ...
}

public class MyCoolDB implements Serializable{
   List<Employee> employers;
   List<Department> departments;
   ...
}
```

Далее в твоем классе где у тебя идет чтение и запись всех этих объектов. Для чтения готового объекта-хранилища из файла:

```
    ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
    MyCoolDB myCoolDB = is.readObject();
```

Для записи этого объекта в файл:

```
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename2));
    oos.writeObject(myCoolDB);
```

Хранить в том виде в котором ты хочешь опасно тем, что файл не имеет структуры понятной машине, и ещё проще эту структуру нарушить. По этому лучше все накопленные данные хранить/передавать в сериализованном виде, но для больших проектов это тоже не вариант, так как объектов у тебя может накопиться уже на несколько гигабайт, а это файле хранить уже будет накладно, да и данные можешь начать терять если на пример вырубили свет до того, как ты корректно выключил своё приложение и не успел сериализовать все данные. По этому нужно изучать *java.persistence*, но и сериализация очень часто в проектах используется, по этому про неё тоже почитай - там все легко.

P.S.: А уже после изучения теории по языку, обязательно нужно изучать теорию по паттернам проектирования ПО, так как в общем-то архитектура твоего приложения будет необслуживаемой, если грамотно не разграничить данные, обработчики данных, способы представления (ну это конечно же я про MVC - ужасный и могучий паттерн :) )